Injectivity radius, diameter and area -- $i(M)\cdot diam(M)\le \frac{\pi}{4} a(M)$
Consider 2-dimsional compact Riemannian manifold $M$. Denote its  injectivity radius as $i(M)$, diameter as $diam(M)$, area as $a(M)$, then I guess there is
$$
i(M)\cdot diam(M)\le \frac{\pi}{4} a(M)
$$
whether it is right? And how to prove it? This maybe hard to prove, I am interested in this kind of problem, what book or paper should I read? Thanks.

Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systolic_geometry and the references given there.

@MoisheKohan  Thanks, I am reading Systolic geometry and topology, although very slowly. The problem seemly means a sphere theorem. There should be a $h>0$ such that if $h \frac{\pi}{4} a(M)\le i(M)\cdot diam(M)\le \frac{\pi}{4} a(M)$, then $M$ is 2-sphere.
